# Get Average from multiple columns from .csv files and save it to a master sheet in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi to all the community.
My question is this:
Is there a way to retrieve the average from multiple .csv files and paste it to a master sheet in excel using a macro without the need of opening the .csv?

### I've tried this code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim file_text_tmp As String
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("E:\Files")

field_num = 3
delimiter = ","

Col = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
   Cells(1, Col) = Val(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 11), 5))
   Open objFile.Path For Input As #1
     Row = 2
     Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, file_text_tmp
        If field_num > 1 Then
           For k = 1 To field_num - 1
              file_text_tmp = Right(file_text_tmp, Len(file_text_tmp) - InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter))
           Next k

        End If
        If InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter) = 0 Then
           Cells(Row, Col) = file_text_tmp
           Col = Col + 1
        Else
           Cells(Row, Col) = Left(file_text_tmp, InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter) - 1)
           Col = Col + 1
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
     Loop
   Close #1
   Col = Col + 1
Next objFile
'Rows("1:6").Delete
'Average Data
Row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For i = 1 To Col - 1
   With Cells(Row, i)
      .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Row - 1, i)))
      .Font.Bold = True
   End With
Next i

End Sub
```

---

But it only put all my data in one cell because my .csv archives have multiple columns separated by commas.
Thanks and I really appreciate the help.

More details:

Each .csv has this>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqBo.png)

and I have several files like these>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbqDU.png)

So I need to put a lot of those .csv files into a folder and then with a Macro calculate the average for each .csv and save it to a Master Excel.
I'm stuck in the average x_x

In other words, I want to get the average of each column and save that line into a master spreadsheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQlEj.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample extracted from one of your .csv files and the result you need in the Excel sheet? I cannot understand very well what you try to do in your code...

Comment: I suggest accessing the files via Power Query; combining the resultant tables; averaging the results; then writing that to the worksheet.

Comment: Or open your CSV files diectly in excel, and copy your data from there: no need to manually parse out the values from each line: this is not always easy and Excel already handles that for you.  "Is there a way to retrieve the average" is also pretty vague - what *exactly* do you need to do?

Comment: I have hundreds of .csv files that I need to extract the average from and put them in one excel, I know I can do it manualy but i'd take ages to finish